# how do jQuery object references work?

Tags: jquery

I have a hypothetical question, something where by knowledge is a wee bit fuzzy.

If I have a jquery object: `Common.$footer = $('.footer');`

And I declare it when the footer doesn't exist, but then the footer gets added later, will the reference work then?

Or a similar scenario if I have did the same when the footer was showing, then it removed, and I used it.

I'm wondering if its ok to setup some references early on in my code, that I can use just later and test if object exists with:

```
Common.$footer[0] && MyFuncCall();
```

Also, if I add a element in later on, is it ok to just grab it with $('.my-dynmically-added-el') ? or do I need to use .live or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no references. Anyway...

`$(selector)` returns a *fixed set of elements* that *currently* match the selector.

If this result is empty then, *it will always be empty*: the resulting jQuery objects can -- and should -- be considered immutable, even if the elements they represent can be mutated.

Thus:

```
x = $('.footer')
// if x.length == 0 then...
// a long time later, assuming x is not assigned to again...
// x.length == 0 is still true
```

There is [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), but that is different.

Happy coding.

Comment: So I could in theory add a $(document).live(function( {}); and inside, keep checking if .footer is set and then update Common.$footer

Comment: @Baconbeastnz `live` is for events. When (if) an event gets handled far up in the document (event handler) the target element will be selector-matched and, if that is successful, the appropriate handler called. There is really no problem "just grabbing [the element] it dynamically later on": selectors are quite fast. If you use the same element multiple times within the same function, *then*, by all means, cache it to a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors specified like this `$(selector)` are run once at the time the object is created.  If the object doesn't exist at the time you create the jQuery object, then the jQuery object will be empty.  They do not magically fill themselves in sometime later when the object starts to exist.  That's just how they work.

There are methods (using event bubbling) to handle events generated by future objects using `.delegate()` or `.on()`, but that is different than what you've described so far.

If you want a jQuery object that refers directly to an object that will be created in the future, then the only way to have a jQuery object that refers to that object is to create that jQuery object after that object exists.